# Which tag to use for "time slice" or "time quantum"?

Tags: support, tags

I'm having trouble finding a tag for "time slice" or "time quantum". Stack Overflow has lots of questions on the subject:

- [time slice Linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=time+slice+Linux+site%3Astackoverflow.com)
- [time slice Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=time+slice+Windows+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

What tag should we use for a thread's preemptive time slice?

Comment: Since the terms are misleading, (grossly so in the case of 'quantum' - a term that implies indivisibility), I suggest no tag:)

Comment: In the case of questions that involve thread signaling/scheduling/dispatching, maybe [operating-systems] or [multithreading]?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit - I don't think the terms are misleading. The terms have well established meaning in Computer Science with respect to scheduling in preemptive operating systems and to a lesser extent threading. I think you would be hard pressed to find a modern book on Operating Systems without a discussion that involves them.

Comment: Well, the first time I saw the term 'quantum; applied to the running state of a thread was in Microsoft documentation.   That would be the same doc that invented 'give up the remainder of their time-slice' and 'recommend no more than 16 threads', and did not mention I/O interrupts:(    Anyway, I don't want to start a war over that:)   IMHO, the existing tags cover the scheduling issue OK.